# How to read the null string with Streamreader c#

Tags: c#, null, streamreader

I am reading the file which has data as below

```
123456788|TUUKKA|RASK|01/01/85|HOCKEY|123
123456786|TOM|BRADY|01/01/75|FOOTBALL|123
123456787|RAJON|RONDO|01/01/80|BASKETBALL|ABC
123456785|DUSTIN|PEDROIA|01/01/83|BASEBALL|
123456789|DAVID|ORTIZ|01/01/77|BASEBALL|123
```

and splitting it with the delimiter '|', but I am the stream reader is not reading the line 4 which contains a null at the end.How do I handle this?

This is my code for reading and splitting the text file line

```
string s = string.Empty;
using (System.IO.StreamReader File = new System.IO.StreamReader(Path))
{
    File.ReadLine();//Removing the first line
    while ((s = File.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string[] str = s.Split('|');
        UpdateRecords.Athelete(str);
    }
}
```

this is my `UpdateRecords.Athelete(str)` code:

```
public static void Athelete(string[] Records) {
    tblAthlete athlete = new tblAthlete();
    using (SportEntities sportEntities = new SportEntities()) {
        var temp = Convert.ToInt32(Records[0]);
        if (sportEntities.tblAthletes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.SSN == temp) == null) {
            athlete.SSN = Convert.ToInt32(Records[0]);
            athlete.First_Name = Records[1];
            athlete.Last_Name=Records[2];
            athlete.DOB = Convert.ToDateTime(Records[3]);
            athlete.SportsCode = Records[4];
            athlete.Agency_Code = Records[5];
            sportEntities.tblAthletes.Add(athlete);
            sportEntities.SaveChanges();
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "is not reading the line"? And when you say "contains a null at the end" what exactly do you mean? (Is there a U+0000 character at the end of the line, or do you mean there just isn't anything after the `|`?)

Comment: You can use a different overloading of split `.Split("|".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`

Comment: Yes, there is no value after '|' at the end of the 4th line.

Comment: The streamreader is just removing the 4th line and proccessing all other lines properly.

Comment: Please explain better where do you get the error. Do you get an error message inside the code of UpdateRecord.Athelete ?

Comment: it there just isn't a value after the `|` (rather than being a `nul` char), it won't be "removing the 4th line" - I would guess that it is your `UpdateRecords.Athelete(str);` method that is doing that... but we can't see that method!

Comment: @Kushal No there is not such thing `The streamreader is just removing the 4th line and proccessing all other lines properly.`

Comment: @MarcGravell inside the method i am checking if there exists a record for the given SSN ,if no recods exists then I am adding the records to the data base.

Comment: @Kushal I've edited the code from the comments into the question; now, `string[] str = s.Split('|');` will still have 6 elements for the line in question, even if the last element is empty (unless you use the specific split options). I wonder if you have a database constraint or similar on that column?

Comment: @MarcGravell The column is an FK referenced to another table PK and it can accept null values.

Answer (score 2):

If we put:

```
athlete.Agency_Code = Records[5];
```

together with (from comments):

> The column is an FK referenced to another table PK and it can accept null values.

the problem becomes clear. An empty string (`""`) is **not** a `null`; it is an empty string! It sounds like you simply want something like:

```
var agencyCode = Records[5];
athlete.Agency_Code = string.IsNullOrEmpty(agencyCode) ? null : agencyCode;
```